# Python difflib: create diff by comparing list of lines with a single, large, combined line

Tags: python, diff, difflib

#### Problem

Let's say I have a list of text segments `t1`:

```
t1 = [
    'Hello everybody, ',
    'this is by ',
    'far the best ',
    'chicken I had ',
    'in my entire ',
    'life.'
]
```

And on the other hand I have the combined and slightly changed text `t2`:

```
t2 = 'Hello everybody, this was by far the best beef I had in my entire life.'
```

Is there a way how a can create a diff that shows me the difference in each segment? So, the result should then look similar to this:

```
  Hello everybody,
- this is by
+ this was by
  far the best
- chicken I had
+ beef I had
  in my entire
  life.
```

So somehow I need to map that combined text back to the single segments. Is there any function within difflib (or other 3rd party libraries) that does this for me?

#### Current Solution

Currently I create a diff by first combining `t1` as well and then create a detailed diff, that shows changes within the line:

```
d = difflib.Differ()
diff = d.compare([''.join(t1)], [t2])
```

Now I have to evaluate the output and try to map everything back to the segments that I used before. I think this will work, but before I put a lot of effort into this solution, I thought it might be worth trying to find out, if there is a simpler solution, that maybe automatically does this kind of re-mapping.

#### A little background for whoever is interested

The reason why I end up with this segmented text on the one hand and the combined text on the other is the following: For each text segment, there are timestamps (stored in a different file) that define at which time the text was spoken. This is important for highlighting the text while playing back a video (think of it like subtitles). Users should now be able to submit corrections to this text and since I would like them to be able to edit within the whole document, without limiting boundaries, I simply present the combined text. Now, when the user makes an edit, I have to use the result and try to figure out in which segments the edit occured and then update (or combine or delete) the segments accordingly.